# О связанности корня -лож-

Tags: словообразование, грамматика

Как же всё-таки объяснить, почему не употребляется слово ЛОЖИТЬ без приставки или постфикса? Куда исчезло нормальное русское слово и почему его заменяет слово с другим корнем - класть? Когда это произошло и в связи с чем?

Comment: Обсуждалось что-то похожее здесь.
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/1112/этимология-класть-и-положить
Чёткого ответа на вопрос ПОЧЕМУ там, правда, нет.

Comment: Я читала эту статью, это интересно как предположение, но где доказательства? Тогда и слово "голубой" должно уйти из языка, это тоже непристойно. К тому же сейчас получается наоборот: бОльшая часть носителей языка не связывает его значение с "ложе", "постель"и, к несчастью, не знает французского аналога. Что мешает вернуть его в нормированное словоупотребление?

Comment: По моему личному мнению, ничего не мешает. Но, может быть, я чего-то не знаю.

Comment: >это интересно как предположение, но где доказательства?

Нет доказательств. И определённого ответа на вопрос нет, о чём я сразу написал в 1-ом комментарии. Просто нельзя говорить "ложить", а почему нельзя -- что-то пока вразумительной причины лично я не слышал.

Вообще, та статья написана, конечно, по стилю ближе к жёлтой прессе, но сама идея о забытом запрете мне понравилась. И потом она объясняет почему **простой** русскоязычный народ говорить "ложить" Украины до Сибири (некоторые даже не подозревают, что здесь что-то не так). А интеллигенции -- нельзя! :-)

Comment: Вообще, та статья написана, конечно, по стилю ближе к жёлтой прессе (немного вульгарно), но сама идея о забытом запрете мне понравилась. И потом, если допустить, что их догадка верна, в качестве гипотезы, то она объясняет почему **простой** русскоязычный народ говорит "ложить" от Украины до Сибири (некоторые даже не подозревают, что здесь что-то не так). А интеллигенции -- нельзя! :-)

Comment: Я тоже подозреваю, что это верное объяснение неупотребления слова в ТО время, но сейчас? Это же вошло в нормы на уровне языка, а не речи.

Comment: Мне кажется, это как раз тот случай, когда язык используется как знак "касты". То есть признак "культурного человека". Ведь логично (естественно) может сказать и "простой человек". А вот исключения доступны только специально обученным людям.

Answer (score 2):

Пусть сначала из заданий ЕГЭ уберут вариант "ложить" как грамматическую ошибку, а потом можно и возвращать это слово как норму.

Answer (score 1):

> Как же всё-таки объяснить, почему не употребляется слово ЛОЖИТЬ без приставки или постфикса?

Никак. Причинно-следственной связи Вы тут не установите, полагаю, что Вы это понимаете не хуже меня. Могло получиться наоборот, в родственных языках такого разделения тоже нет.

С уверенностью можно только сказать, что полностью синонимичная пара -лож-/-клад- должна была найти какое-то разрешение в виде разделения значений или функций в языке. Полных синонимов любой язык обычно избегает.

> не употребляется слово ЛОЖИТЬ без приставки или постфикса?

Ложе, ложа  - не пойдет?

> Когда это произошло и в связи с чем?

Если не ошибаюсь, то по древнерусским источникам ограничений на глаголы с "лож" не существовало. Утрата большинства временнЫх форм русского глагола (XIII-XV век-?) и окончательное оформление категории вида (веком-двумя позже) привело к появлению упомянутой синонимичной избыточности. Впрочем, это навскидку, даты и факты можно уточнить, я сейчас в цейтноте, поправьте, кто владеет вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю просто в идеолекте тех людей, которые составляли первые словари, не было слова "ложить", вместо него они всегда говорили "класть", что они и отразили в словаре. И не важно, что скорей всего они относились к меньшинству, может быть даже к очень маленькому меньшинству. А дальше, так как у нас почему-то воспринимают словари не как описание языка, а как предписание как говорить, то граммар-наци уцепились за это слово, стали считать его признаком необразованности. Это уже вопрос психологии, а не лингвистики. Лингвисты отлично понимают, что слово "ложить" конечно же в русском языке есть, если носители языка в подавляющем большинстве его используют каждодневно. Но из-за давления "общественности" не включают его в словари.