# Источник того, что корректно "я клала", а не "я ложила"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Доброго всем времени суток!
Укажите, пожалуйста, источник того, что корректно "я клала бумагу", а не "я ложила...".

Или поправьте меня в том случае, если грамотными (допустимыми) являются оба варианта.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А  почему  не  сказать  правильно ( вместо  корректно ) ?

Answer (score 7):

Действительно, правильно только "класть", "положить". Неверно: "ложить", "покласть". Таких слов в словарях нет. Любой толковый или орфографический словарь  будет тому подтверждением.

Обсуждали [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17193/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6).

Comment: Ларf, Вопрос заключался именно в указании источника.Именно того, что "ложила" НЕ КОРРЕКТНО. Какой орфографический словарь именно Вы имеете ввиду? 
Читаем:
Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка Владимира Даля:  "Глаг. ложить часто пополняет собою глаг. класть, по духу языка".
Академический словарь Ушакова: областное и просторечное (но не неправильное!)слово.
Какой орфографический словарь именно Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Современные, конечно. Кстати, просторечие - это как раз  за пределами литературной нормы. Слова "ложить" в современных словарях нет.

Comment: Зато  в  устной  речи   оно  доминирует.  Примеров  полно  в  социальных  сетях.  В  Одноклассниках,  например.

Comment: В устной речи он вовсе не доминирует. Тоже достаточно редко встречается — может быть, в вашем городе это и стандартная замена, но в Москве, например — нет. Исключение — когда говорящий намеренно играется, имитируя чистаканкретно неграмотную речь.

Comment: Далеко не все пользователи социальных сетей являются знатоками русского языка. Особенно в Одноклассниках

Answer (score 5):

"Корректно" в каком виде? И для какой цели? Никто не будет спорить, что слово "ложить" в русском языке есть. Тем не менее, оно

- за пределами литературной нормы письменной речи ("Зайдя в дом, Марк принялся класть вещи на полку, одну за другой, и даже не взглянул на детей, пока мешок его не опустел")
- за пределами литературной нормы устного языка. Да, как это ни странно, литературный язык это и устный язык тоже: "Слушай, я тут подумал — надо бы положить деньги на счёт. У тебя нету сотни?"
- безусловно присутствует в просторечии и, наверняка, в диалектах — не соответствует понятию "грамотной речи", но отдельными людьми на местах употребляется (в Национальном корпусе употребимость порядка 0.35 на миллион слов — очень мало, но есть). В русском даже в городах есть некоторые лексические вариации — скажем в Москве ни один умеренно-образованный человек "ложить" использовать не будет. А вот в городах подальше на востоке, в Сибири, как мне рассказывали, для грамотных людей это вполне допустимо. "Класть" же там как раз для подчёркнуто "корректной" речи. Сам не проверял. За что купил, за то и продаю. :)

Даль, мне казалось, умер в позапрошлом веке. Даже словарь Ожегова прижизненных изданий автора не во всем подходят для *современного* русского языка. Образца 2014 года. Хотя, безусловно, ближе. Далее словари живут уже за счёт правок более современных авторов, дополнения новыми словами и за счёт уточнениея, пополнения смысла старых.

Answer (score 3):

"Куда шапку ложишь! Кого за стол садишь!" Необязательно обращаться к словарям,чтобы понять, что перед нами просторечный народный стиль. Но почему эти грамматические формы не используются в современной литературной речи? Вариант ответа предлагается в качестве версии.

У глаголов «класть и лежать» разные по происхождению корни. Лежать – от legti (находиться в горизонтальном положении), класть – от klado – стлать, покрывать, укладывать слоями. Это глаголы общеславянского происхождения с и.е. корнем. В видовой паре КЛАСТЬ/ПОЛОЖИТЬ происходит сближение значений, но почему мы не пользуемся парами ЛОЖИТЬ/ПОЛОЖИТЬ, КЛАСТЬ/ПОКЛАСТЬ? Для ответа на этот вопрос попробуем сравнить наш вариант с глаголами СИДЕТЬ – САЖАТЬ – ПОСАДИТЬ.

Обратим внимании на то, что суффикс А часто обозначает несов. вид, а суффикс И – сов. вид. Также обратим внимание на то, что приставка ПО может обозначать завершение действия (сов. вид) или действие в течение какого-то времени.

Сидеть  →   сажать/(садить)  → посадить/посажать:
Лежать  →    (ложить)/класть  → положить/(покласть)

Итак, мы выбираем: СИДЕТЬ – САЖАТЬ – ПОСАДИТЬ и ЛЕЖАТЬ – КЛАСТЬ – ПОЛОЖИТЬ. Вариант «ложить» плох тем, что у него суффикс сов.вида И. Вариант «покласть»  нехорош тем, что у него приставка ПО может быть неоднозначно истолкована. А вот в глаголах «посадить и положить» значение сов. вида передает как приставка ПО, так и суффикс И.

Comment: У кучи глаголов, несовершенного вида суффикс И. Следить, просить, бить, курить и так далее. Они от этого какими-то плохими становятся? Ничем глагол "ложить" не плох, это всё за уши притянуто. Точнее просто в идеолекте составителя соловаря когда-то давно не было слова ложить, а было слово класть. Он это и отразил в словаре. Ну а граммар-наци ведь воспринимают словари не как описание языка, а как предписание как надо говорить. Дальше это стало переходить в другие словари

Answer (score 1):

Лично я усвоила это слово ещё будучи дошкольником по замечательному нашему фильму "Доживём до понедельника". Очень уж запомнилось, когда Тихонов (мой любимый актёр) сделал замечание учительнице, что нет такого слова "ложить"!
На всю жизнь так и запомнилось.